# Swift - Subclass an Enum (or something to that effect)

Tags: ios, swift, enums, protocols, subclass

I want to do something like this...

```
enum SpriteFrames:Int {

    case N
    case NE
    case E
    case SE
    case S
    case SW
    case W
    case NW
}

enum DroidSpriteFramesIdle:Int {

    var image:String {
        switch self {
        case N:
            return "droid_n"
        case NE:
            return "droid_ne"
        case E:
            return "droid_e"
        case SE:
            return "droid_se"
        case S:
            return "droid_s"
        case SW:
            return "droid_sw"
        case W:
            return "droid_w"
        case NW:
            return "droid_nw"
        }
    }

}
enum DroidSpriteFramesMove:Int {

    var image:String {
        switch self {
        case N:
            return "droid_move_n"
        case NE:
            return "droid_move_ne"
        case E:
            return "droid_move_e"
        case SE:
            return "droid_move_se"
        case S:
            return "droid_move_s"
        case SW:
            return "droid_move_sw"
        case W:
            return "droid_move_w"
        case NW:
            return "droid_move_nw"
        }
    }

}
```

...where `DroidSpriteFramesIdle` and `DroidSpriteFramesMove` subclass `SpriteFrames`, or conform to it as a protocol or something to that effect. Basically, I want to have a lot of Enums that all have the same list of cases for the directions (N, NE, E etc) but have their own list of unique values for those common directions. I don't want to use classes, because that would result in the creation of instances when assigned. Open to alternative ideas though, I'm quite new to Swift. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an alias for that enum which can act like a subclass

ex Apple's default:

```
public enum UITextFieldViewMode : Int {

    case Never
    case WhileEditing
    case UnlessEditing
    case Always
}
```

ex alias:

```
public typealias AutoCompleteButtonViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode
```

your function:

```
func showButtonWithViewMode(buttonViewMode: AutoCompleteButtonViewMode) {

    // Code here
}
```

usage:

```
showButtonWithViewMode(.WhileEditing)
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe assigning enum raw values would be more readable.

```
enum Direction:String {     
    case N = "n"
    case NE = "ne"
    case E = "e"
    case SE = "se"
    case S = "s"
    case SW = "sw"
    case W = "w"
    case NW = "nw"
}

enum Action: String {
    case Idle = "droid"
    case Move = "droid_move"
}

func spriteFramesDroid(direction:Direction, action:Action) -> String {
    return "\(action.rawValue)_\(direction.rawValue)"

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Ashraf, I wasn't able to adapt your suggestion to my code, but it did put me down a path that resulted in a a satisfactory conclusion. I ended up writing some functions that accept enums as parameters. It's little bit off the track from my initial approach but it ticks all the boxes e.g. has minimal duplication of code and is still a functional approach that avoids unnecessary instantiating. Final code here:

```
enum Direction: Int {
    case N
    case NE
    case E
    case SE
    case S
    case SW
    case W
    case NW
}
enum Action: Int {
    case Idle
    case Move
}
func spriteFramesDroid(direction:Direction, action:Action) -> String {

    switch action {
        case .Idle:
            switch direction {
                case .N:
                    return "droid_n"
                case .NE:
                    return "droid_ne"
                case .E:
                    return "droid_e"
                case .SE:
                    return "droid_se"
                case .S:
                    return "droid_s"
                case .SW:
                    return "droid_sw"
                case .W:
                    return "droid_w"
                case .NW:
                    return "droid_nw"
            }
        case .Move:
            switch direction {
                case .N:
                    return "droid_move_n"
                case .NE:
                    return "droid_move_ne"
                case .E:
                    return "droid_move_e"
                case .SE:
                    return "droid_move_se"
                case .S:
                    return "droid_move_s"
                case .SW:
                    return "droid_move_sw"
                case .W:
                    return "droid_move_w"
                case .NW:
                    return "droid_move_nw"
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your solution is just better than what I have thought. Good job! :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can make use of this article specially the enum section. It shows something a bit relevant to what you have in mind.  http://www.objc.io/issue-16/power-of-swift.html

Quoting from the above website

"They are very similar. If you change the naming of the cases, the only thing that’s different is the associated value. If you also add a value to the Nil case of the optional, you end up with the Either type:

`enum Either<A,B> {
    case Left(A)
    case Right(B)
}`

The Either type is used a lot in functional programming when you want to represent a choice between two things. For example, if you have function that returns either an integer or an error, you could use Either. If you would want to store either booleans or strings in a dictionary, you could use Either as the key type.

Theoretical aside: sometimes enums are so-called sum types, because they represent a sum of different types. In the case of Either, they represent the sum of A and B. Structs or tuples are called product types because they represent the product of different types. See also: algebraic data types."

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer: "**Provide context for links** Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."

Comment: The link is interesting but does not answer the question. I think that Swift simply can't do what is requested.